# After sleep, resume shows a black screen

Tags: suspend

I have two Ubuntu computers both with AMD chips and nVidia graphics. Both of them fail to sleep/resume properly. when they sleep they actually turn off the system off. That is I must I press the power button on the case to turn them on rather than press a key or move the mouse. When I resume by pressing the power button after a few seconds I get a blank/black screen and nothing more. Can someone please help me?

I've search google and these forums and basically found there's no single answer. The answers on this forum are from around 2011 and 2013 and point to a kernel problem that was fixed, but surely I have a newer kernel than the 2011 or 2013 era. My OSes are Ubuntu 16.04 and Ubuntu Mate 17.04.